# Sparql in combination with DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

i want to display the countries with their net value/income or something similiar through accessing the data through DBPedia. and further insert them into an already created table.
Unfortunately i dont get any results with my code.
[image: Screenshot of SPARQL query and result]

Comment: not posting the SPARQL query here as text is a bit unfortunate. People now have to use your screenshot, and write the whole query again ...

Comment: that said, `dbr:income` is clearly wrong, `dbr:` is the prefix for namespace `http://dbpedia.org/resource/` which is for the entities, but not the properties. You should either use `dbp:` or `dbo::` - but, even better is to make your whole SPARQL query self-contained, i.e. define every prefix by yourself in the query to make sure that only the namespace you want is used, not any pre-deployed by the service. Like you did for `rdfs:` and `dbo:` for example.

Comment: In the meantime, I checked DBpedia - there is no property "income" for any country. So, from where do you have this idea? It is mostly better to check some examples, in your case some countries via the web browser and see which did is available and which not. All I can see are some GDP related properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query to list the type of entities that has a dbp:income as a property. you will notice that dbo:Country is not the list, that's why the result you got was empty.

```
prefix dbp:  <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
select distinct  ?type
where {
    ?s a ?type.
    ?s dbp:income ?income
}
```

My suggestion is to use dbp:gdpNominal instead of the dbp:income property in your query :

```
prefix dbp:  <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select distinct  ?country_name ?income
where {
    ?country a dbo:Country. 
    ?country rdfs:label ?country_name.  FILTER (lang(?country_name) = 'en')  
    ?country  dbp:gdpNominal ?income.
}
```